Can Force a cache-min-ttl For Only PTR Records
I have configured Unbound to act as a recursive DNS server. Trying to understand is it possible to configure it so that it caches a specific type of record, PTR, longer than what the TTL is in the record. Do it globally for all PTR records.
cache-min-ttl is applied to all record types, I do not see a way to limit its scope.

Unbound has a configuration option called cache-ttl-* that allows you to set a custom cache TTL for specific record types. To cache PTR records longer than the TTL in the record, you can use cache-ttl-ptr.
For example, to cache PTR records for 1 hour (3600 seconds) globally, try adding the following line to your Unbound configuration file:
cache-ttl-ptr: 3600
This should override the TTL in the PTR records and cache them for 1 hour. Note that this setting applies to all PTR records, so be cautious when using it.
But if you want to cache PTR records longer than the TTL but still respect the TTL to some extent, you can use cache-min-ttl-ptr and cache-max-ttl-ptr together. For example:
cache-min-ttl-ptr: 3600
cache-max-ttl-ptr: 86400
This will cache PTR records for at least 1 hour (3600 seconds) and at most 1 day (86400 seconds), regardless of the TTL in the record.
Again- these settings apply globally to all PTR records, so make sure to test and monitor the effects on your DNS traffic- it’ll be quite high!
